# hyperledger fabric ELIFECYCLE

Tags: node.js, npm, hyperledger-fabric

Good morning everyone, I have been having this error for 3 months and couldn't solve it
if you have any information regarding that please help.

I am running two chaincodes and 7 peers ( CA,MSP,chaincode container per peer) for a total of 42 docker containers
everything runs smoothly till it's time to do transactions, all the docker peers containing chaincode exit with this error except the first one started

I don't know if it is a hlf related error or a npm related error, and I checked everywhere, this type of error is sometimes hlf and sometimes npm, and there is no clear solution to solve it either way!
I gave up and I am asking for help now which is much appreciated as this is my graduation project

I am using hyperledger fabric v 2 and using npm,node,java script here are the contents of my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "student-smart-contract",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "smart contract for courses",
    "main": "index.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=12",
        "npm": ">=5"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "init-lint": "eslint --init",
        "lint": "eslint .",
        "pretest": "npm run lint",
        "test": "nyc mocha --recursive",
        "start": "fabric-chaincode-node start"
    },
    "engineStrict": true,
    "author": "Hyperledger",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "ajv": "^5.5.2",
        "fabric-contract-api": "^2.2.1",
        "fabric-shim": "^2.2.1",
        "grpc": "^1.24.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "chai": "^4.1.2",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
        "mocha": "^8.0.1",
        "nyc": "^14.1.1",
        "sinon": "^6.0.0",
        "sinon-chai": "^3.2.0"
    },
    "nyc": {
        "exclude": [
            "coverage/**",
            "test/**",
            "index.js",
            ".eslintrc.js"
        ],
        "reporter": [
            "text-summary",
            "html"
        ],
        "all": true,
        "check-coverage": true,
        "statements": 100,
        "branches": 100,
        "functions": 100,
        "lines": 100
    }
}
```

and below is the error, thanks in advance

```
> Executing task: docker logs --tail 1000 -f 0f3588111617d412d11768c32df6f9f724da08c46217257953a32c90e6288d98 <

+ CHAINCODE_DIR=/usr/local/src
+ cd /usr/local/src
+ npm start -- --peer.address peer0.Aswan.com:8052

> student-smart-contract@1.0.0 start /usr/local/src
> fabric-chaincode-node start "--peer.address" "peer0.Aswan.com:8052"

2021-10-27T12:33:11.636Z info [c-api:contracts-spi/bootstrap.js]                  No metadata file supplied in contract, introspection will generate all the data  
2021-10-27T12:33:11.643Z info [c-api:./lib/contract.js]                           Creating new Contract  
2021-10-27T12:33:11.644Z info [c-api:./lib/contract.js]                           Creating new Contract  
2021-10-27T12:33:11.644Z info [c-api:./lib/contract.js]                           Creating new Contract  
2021-10-27T12:33:11.645Z info [c-api:./lib/contract.js]                           Creating new Contract  
2021-10-27T12:33:11.645Z info [c-api:./lib/contract.js]                           Creating new Contract "org.hyperledger.fabric" 
2021-10-27T12:33:11.712Z info [c-api:lib/chaincode.js]                            Registering with peer peer0.Aswan.com:8052 as chaincode "CoursesSmartContract:e2401ca75fc0abab992210baee01c0d10f4d5cbb48e701d5818772f8fda3a82a"  
2021-10-27T12:33:11.727Z info [c-api:fabric-shim/cli]                             
Command succeeded
  
2021-10-27T12:33:11.774Z info [c-api:lib/handler.js]                              Successfully registered with peer node. State transferred to "established"  
2021-10-27T12:33:11.775Z info [c-api:lib/handler.js]                              Successfully established communication with peer node. State transferred to "ready"  
2021-10-27T12:33:41.770Z error [c-api:lib/handler.js]                             Received unknown message from the peer. Exiting.  
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! student-smart-contract@1.0.0 start: `fabric-chaincode-node start "--peer.address" "peer0.Aswan.com:8052"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the student-smart-contract@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-27T12_33_41_777Z-debug.log
```

and when I followed /root/.npm/
I got this

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--peer.address',
1 verbose cli   'peer0.Aswan.com:8052'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle student-smart-contract@1.0.0~prestart: student-smart-contract@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle student-smart-contract@1.0.0~start: student-smart-contract@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle student-smart-contract@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle student-smart-contract@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/usr/local/src/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
9 verbose lifecycle student-smart-contract@1.0.0~start: CWD: /usr/local/src
10 silly lifecycle student-smart-contract@1.0.0~start: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'fabric-chaincode-node start "--peer.address" "peer0.Aswan.com:8052"'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle student-smart-contract@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle student-smart-contract@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: student-smart-contract@1.0.0 start: `fabric-chaincode-node start "--peer.address" "peer0.Aswan.com:8052"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid student-smart-contract@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /usr/local/src
16 verbose Linux 5.11.0-25-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start" "--" "--peer.address" "peer0.Aswan.com:8052"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error student-smart-contract@1.0.0 start: `fabric-chaincode-node start "--peer.address" "peer0.Aswan.com:8052"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the student-smart-contract@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I see that you are using a lot of docker containers and a lot of peers. You said you are having two chaincodes and 7 peers. How many orgs do you have? And how many peers does each have? Also, where is each chaincode installed? What type of transaction do you try to do and you get the error?

Comment: also 7 orgs one peer per org, my transactions are those of my smart contract, do u want me to show you the code?

Comment: So, you are invoking the chaincode with node sdk? Or what are you using exactly? Which peer do you invoke? is this happening with all peers? I mean have you tried the same structure in another network that has only one org an one peer for example to see if this is something with a particular peer node?

Comment: this happens before even invoking anything, but yes I do invoke it with node sdk, I haven't tried this structure with another network because that network with that structure was the whole point of it, and having to test it this way will mean that I have to re-build everything from scratch but just for one node which defeats the purpose :(
the error happens with 6 orgs were they just exit the containers  ( I check them from docker extension in vs code..)

Comment: The "Received Unkown Message from Peer" (that comes from https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node/blob/e6eb845efc0f32976b87ff81a4fc750f64a98130/libraries/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js#L332)  Is not often seen.   

Normally there is a defined set of states that the peer-chaincode move through before transacting.  

It would be worth checking the peer logs as well. 

You said that this is a single org with 7 peers... but you also mention 6 orgs?

Comment: It would be useful to know as well how you've constructed the Fabric configuration, is it an extension of the test-network... 

And out curiosity - why so many peers in one org?

Comment: hey, sorry for the late reply I have been stuck in this error since then and I am very frustrated
here is my network configuration
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t6jLQnOZI4WsrpZ28ArQhdQASXzTDLvt?usp=sharing
so you are suggesting that this is a problem with my chaincode? where is the part that moves states ? I couldn't find it anywhere...I always see that they init ledger but I didn't do that, I did check the peer logs and they are mentioned above

Comment: the error is in my start script, looking closely I noticed an extra "--", how do I remove that from the start script?